# change culture on actionlink click without refreshing the page with resource files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working in asp.net mvc 4 with EF 5 in .NET Framework 4 (thank you Azure for not being 4.5 yet).
I'm trying to let a user change the current language settings by pressing on a button. The content that needs to change is saved in resource files.

first I get the browser settings in my web.config

```
<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto"/>
```

Then I try and change it via hyperlink.
Here's an example of the link that I'm using:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("FR", "ChangeLanguage", "Account", new { language = "fr" }, null)</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("EN", "ChangeLanguage", "Account", new { language = "en" }, null)</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("NL", "ChangeLanguage", "Account", new { language = "nl" }, null)</li>
```

Here's how I fill the text:

```
@Html.Encode(MyProject.Web.Resources.General.Header_UserBadge_SettingsDeleteCurrentPicture)
```

Here's the controller action they're linked to:

```
public ActionResult ChangeLanguage(string language)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(language);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(language);
        }
```

The resource files are named:

1. General.fr.resx => French
2. General.resx => English
3. General.nl.resx => Dutch

Now obviously this doesn't work. I can't seem to find any examples of what I'm trying to do. All the examples I can find refresh the page.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Can this be done? If yes, how or what am I doing wrong?
2. If this can't be done, then what would be a good solution? Currently redirecting at the end of the action doesn't seem to change language settings.

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the changed language settings by the user in cookie or session and in the `Application_AcquireRequestState` of `Global.asax.cs` set the `CurrentUICulture` and `CurrentCulture` for the `Thread.CurrentThread` from the language stored in cookie/session.

You can also store the user's preferred language in database and by this way the user don't need to set the language every time logs-in.

Comment: Thanks, but this only seems to work on page refresh. I can't get it to work without a redirect.

Comment: You want to change the html displayed to the user without making a page refresh? That's not easy you need a refresh else you have to make ajax calls to refresh the complete page content but that is not a good idea.

Comment: I'm getting the html via resource files. For example: @Html.Encode(MyProject.Web.Resources.General.Header_UserBadge_SettingsDeleteCurrentPicture) I was hoping I could change these dynamically, but if this is not possible, I'll just use a page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way would be to have your links in a `Partial View` and have your Action to return the partial view once you have changed the culture.

```
    public ActionResult ChangeLanguage(string language)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(language);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(language);

         return PartialView("YourPartialView");
    }
```

this action could be called from a jquery/ajax call, so you see no postback will happen

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is that I can't just make my entire GUI in partial views. As I currently have my layout and menu also in partial views, I'd have to load every page with javascript or ajax. (unless I'm wrong here). EDIT: the layout and menu partial also contain elements that need to change for the user language, so making my views partial views would mean I would have to reload them to. This is the entire page that I reload then, which is what I'm trying to go against.

Comment: this **may** help http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx